php artisan cache:clear is giving Illegal instruction (core dumped)
The problem is I installed laravel/telescope in Laravel 11. After that my local server is not running. Each time I try any of the artisan command, it is giving
php artisan cache:clear
Illegal instruction (core dumped)

php artisan migrate
Illegal instruction (core dumped)

php artisan serve

   INFO  Server running on [http://127.0.0.1:8000].  

  Press Ctrl+C to stop the server


On Opening this link, I am getting "This site can’t be reached" in my browser.
I am Using Ubuntu and sqlite database, other Laravel projects are working fine on this machine. How to fix this?

Solved, what it required was ./vendor/bin/pest --init More about it at link
